# SQL: Match timestamps with time-only parameter to group and count unique times across multiple days

Tags: sql, datetime, pyspark, group-by, timestamp

Using **SQL** or **Pyspark**, I want to count the number of unique times in a timestamp across a time frame of 2 months. I want to see the distribution of how often rows are logged to the table. This is because I know there a large proportion of timestamps with the time of 00:00:00, but I want to know how big and the ratio compared to other times.

This query groups and counts the most common datetimes, but I need to exclude the date and only have the time. Apparently, this is not so common thing to do.

```sql
select timestamp,
    count(*) as count
from table_name
where timestamp between '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-28'
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

The SQL/Pyspark is ran on a Spark DB in a Zeppelin Notebook.

Timestamps look like this: `2021-01-01 02:07:55`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select 
  date_format(timestamp, "H m s") as dataTime,
  count(*) as count
from table_name
where timestamp between '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-28'
group by date_format(timestamp, "H m s") 
order by 2 desc
```

Not a good idea name fields with reserved words (`timestamp`).

From [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

Comment: Your right about the reserved word, I'll change it to `datetime`. To simplify this query, the group by can be replaced with `group by 1` as it duplicates the select clause.

Comment: The select query can also be modified to match the format the timestamp gives. `date_format(timestamp, "HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on type of your `timestamp` column, you can extract [hour](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour), [minute](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.minute), [second](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.second) if it is `TimestampType` (with [lpad](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lpad) to add leading zeros), or using [regexp_extract](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) if it is `StringType`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# if your ts column has TimestampType
(df
    .withColumn('ts', F.col('ts').cast('timestamp')) # my assumption ts is timestamp
    .withColumn('time_only', F.concat(
        F.lpad(F.hour('ts'), 2, '0'),
        F.lit(':'),
        F.lpad(F.minute('ts'), 2, '0'),
        F.lit(':'),
        F.lpad(F.second('ts'), 2, '0')
    ))
    .show()
)

# if your ts column is StringType
(df
    .withColumn('ts', F.col('ts').cast('string')) # my assumption ts is string
    .withColumn('time_only', F.regexp_extract('ts', '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', 0))
    .show()
)

# +-------------------+---------+
# |                 ts|time_only|
# +-------------------+---------+
# |2019-01-15 03:00:00| 03:00:00|
# |2019-01-15 20:00:00| 20:00:00|
# |2019-01-15 19:00:00| 19:00:00|
# |2019-01-15 11:00:00| 11:00:00|
# +-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: My timestamp is a TimestampType, thanks for providing an answer if it wasn't too. I added this to do the group by and order by: `df.groupBy(F.col('time_only')).count().orderBy(F.col('count').desc()).show()`

Comment: I also like how you use parenthesis around the multi-line statement instead of putting a \ at the end of each line.